# Read / access "Telegram Messenger" messages via VBA

Tags: vba, telegram

is there a way to access incoming "Telegram Messenger" Messages using VBA.

I am subscripted to a telegram chanel where I get some information, which I would like to evaluate automatically by a programm. But before I can evaluate the message I need to read it somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not seem possible to solve this task with VBA.